# jQuery - Select an element if it only has/contains one link-tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to apply a class to a table row if it only contains one link. I think I can use the `.has()` selector, but I'm not sure how to check if the `<tr>` has one or more `<a>-tags`.

Comment: what you have try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by filtering the `tr`'s and looking for only those containing exactly 1 `a`.

```
$('tr').filter(function(){
   return $('a',this).length==1;
}).addClass('red');
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/0favb7sz/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `filter` method:

```
$('table tr').filter(function() {
    return $('a', this).length === 1;
}).addClass('class');
```